# Is this chip SPI or Serial Interface

Tags: communication

The datasheet for the chip TLC254 says that it uses a serial communication interface at the top of the datasheet, however, it has MOSI MISO SS CS and all the other SPI styled pins. Is it safe to assume that it is SPI or is it Serial? If it is SPI what Mode should I use since there is no mention of the mode in the Datasheet. 
Datasheet: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc2543.pdf

EDIT:
Thanks for bearing with me for I am pretty new to Communication.
I now realize that SPI is a branch of Serial thanks so some awesome people here.

Comment: I think SPI means Serial Peripheral Interface.  There are many different serial interface protocols.

Comment: My question is why does my board's datasheet say Serial, and then give SPI pins like MOSI MISO stuff

Comment: @jsotola I now see what you are saying because of filos comment. But Now my question is whats the difference between SPI and Arduinos inbuilt Serial.write/read(), I though that was what serial protocol was

Comment: `serial protocol` is just a description of the manner in which data is transferred across a serial data link ... SPI, I2C, ethernet, PCI-e and SATA are all examples of a serial data transfer systems ... each having its own protocol

Comment: That makes senes. Thanks!

Comment: the arduino serial.write() uses asynchronous serial communication ... the system uses a start and stop bits with data bits in between .... https://www.microcontrollertips.com/asynchronous-serial-communication-explained-including-ttl-uart-rs232/   ..... the receiver watches the data line ... when the start bit arrives, that means that data bits follow

Comment: SPI is also serial, but the timing of the data transfer is tightly controlled by the master device through the use of a clock signal that is made available on a separate line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This chip is SPI (chip select, data in, data out, clock). SPI is a serial protocol, as is I2C and UART.

You are probably confusing "serial" with "serial port in a PC".

Comment: By serial i mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication

Comment: Section 2 of the Wikipedia article lists SPI as one of the serial protocols.

Comment: that makes sense. Thanks! But then what is the differnce between Arduinos Serial.read/write and SPI?

Comment: One is UART, the other is SPI. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Now that I got the serial interface figured out, could you help me with the code I am a little bit stuck. Thanks!